# Remove custom background from ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, background, icons, jtree

As the title says, how can I do to remove the background from an imageIcon?

Let's say.. I've a `JTree` (but it can be every `JComponent`) and I would like to set an icon for its leaf nodes.

```
myDefaultTreeCellRendere.setLeafIcon(new ImageIcon(icon));
```

The icon has the white background and I would like removing that. Is that possible?
I read some answers on Stackoverflow but there a `BufferedImage` is used and the icon is retrieved from the web and stored in an URL object... My icon is local, instead.

Comment: It would be most optimal to remove the BG in a paint app. like Photo Shop.  Failing that, one hack is to process the image at run-time to remove the 'white pixels'.  This will (obviously) fail if the image itself has any white parts (the whites of their eyes?) which will also become transparent.  If you decide to try removing the BG at run-time, upload the image to an image share site and provide a link. *"I read some answers on Stackoverflow but there a BufferedImage is used and the icon is retrieved from the web and stored in an URL object..."* `</head-desk>` Most things that work for an ..

Comment: .. URL also work for a file!  (And a lot of the code on the net will *hot link* to images via URL.)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use an image format that supports transparency, such as GIF or PNG. You can either look for a new icon with transparent background, or you can modify your current image with an image editor (Photoshop or Gimp will do).

Comment: This should be, and the part about Photo Shopping the image already was, a comment..

Answer (score -2):

What you could do is to give to the ImageIcon object the same size as that of the image. For example, if your image has a sioze of 40x40, you do

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("path_to_image");
img.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
myDefaultTreeCellRendere.setLeafIcon(img);
```

+1 if it works :D

Comment: Thank you. I think there is a problem in your solution because the white background is part of my image. So, I don't think that setting the preferredSize for my icon could fix my problem. Anyway, I'll try :)

Comment: Oh! sorry, there was a missunderstanding. Why don't you simply remove the white area using an image editor. For instance, you could use GIMP or simply paint ?

Comment: *"..there was a missunderstanding."*  You can delete or edit this answer any time you like..